# Codeigniter javascript function keeps failing

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, cart

So i'm coding a donation store inside of codeigniter. I've been working to add the cart function to it, and have made a small card that holds the items for the store, with the ability to add to cart, and a ajax request to post and reload. The thing is, in the first category, it will work fine, success and succesfully adds to cart and reloads. but if i go into the other categories and click on an item, it always returns failure.

```
        <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header p-2">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <?php foreach ($category as $cat) { ?>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#<?= $cat['categ_name']; ?>" data-toggle="tab"><?= $cat['categ_name']; ?></a></li>
                <? } ?>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.card-header -->
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <?php foreach ($category as $pane) { ?>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="<?= $pane['categ_name']; ?>">
            <div class="row">
            <?php foreach ($item as $ditems) { ?>
                <?php if ($ditems['categ_name'] == $pane['categ_name']) { ?>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-6">
                        <div class="flip-card">
                            <div class="flip-card-inner">
                                <div class="flip-card-front">
                                <img src="<?= base_url() ?>assets/itemdb/<?= $ditems['image']; ?>" alt="Image" style="width:200px;height:160px;">
                                <h3><?= $ditems['item_name']; ?></h3>
                                </div>
                            <div class="flip-card-back">
                            <p><b>Price : $<?= $ditems['price']; ?></b></p>
                            <p><?php if ($ditems['package'] == 1) { ?>
                            <a href="">Package Details</a>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                            <p>Quantity : x <?= $ditems['amount']; ?></p>
                            <?= $ditems['descr']; ?></p>
                            <?php } ?>
                        <?php echo form_open(base_url('donation/add_cart_item'), 'class="horizontal-form" '); ?>
                                
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
                                <input type="number"  value="" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity"  placeholder="Enter Quantity">
                            </div>
                            
                        <input type="number"  value="<?= $ditems['catelog_id']; ?>" class="form-control" id="cat_id" name="cat_id"  placeholder="<?= $ditems['catelog_id']; ?>" hidden>
                            
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="button" id="add_cart" class="btn" onClick="sendToCart();">Add To Cart</button>
                        </div>  
                                
                        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <? } ?>
                    <? } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <? } ?>
        </div>
        <!-- /.tab-content -->
    </div><!-- /.card-body -->
</div>
    <!-- /.nav-tabs-custom -->
```

and this is the script im sending it to:

```
 <?php 
  $url =  base_url().'donation/add_cart_item'; 
  ?>
  
 <script>
 
    function sendToCart(){

    var catId = $("#cat_id").val();
    var qty = $("#quantity").val();


    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo $url ?>",
    data: { '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>':'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>', cat_id: catId, quantity: qty, ajax: '1' },
    dataType: "json",
    cache:false,
    success: function() {
    location.reload();
    alert("success");   
    },
    error:function() {
    alert("failure");
    }
    });

    return false; // Stop the browser of loading the page
    }
    
 </script>
```

and the controller :

```
public function add_cart_item(){

        $id = $this->input->post('cat_id');
        $qty = $this->input->post('quantity');

        $item = $this->cart_model->get_item($id);
                        
        $data = array(
                'id'      => $id,
                'qty'     => $qty,
                'price'   => $item['price'],
                'name'    => $item['item_name']
                        );

        $data = $this->security->xss_clean($data);
        
        
        $insert = $this->cart->insert($data);

        if ($insert) {
            if ($this->input->post('ajax') != '1') {
                redirect('store'); // If javascript is not enabled, reload the page with new data
            } else {
                echo 'true'; // If javascript is enabled, return true, so the cart gets updated
            }
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('warning', 'Could not insert the item to cart. Please try again later or contact an Administrator with this error.');
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: So what is the error message?

Comment: This: "_it always returns failure._" - What does? And repeating epascarelgo - what is the error message?

Comment: there is no error message that is produced, the only thing that returns error is inside the ajax :  alert("failure"); ive even used developer tools to trace it but cant find the issue

Comment: I have 3 test items, one in category Main, one in category Points, one in Rares. The item inside the first category, Main, returns full success, its only when i go into the other categories that i get an error, its not even the insert error inside the controller, something with the ajax.

Comment: After messing around a bit, i turned it to an alert to see each stage, it is not accepting the quantity inside the other items. So the first category, any items in there accepts quantity being passed, but in other categories, it doesn't pass the quantity. Also there was this warning inside console : [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #quantity , which i'm guessing its the quantity ID not being unique, but how would i pass a unique id as the quantity and accept it through javascript for a post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `this` inside your `sendToCart` function where `this` refer to button which is clicked . Then , use `.closest()` & `.find()` method to get required input values and pass same to your ajax call . Also , i have added class for *quantity* and *cat_id* add that in your html as well.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function sendToCart(el) {
  //get closest outer div ( tabp pane ) ->find inputs with class
  var catId = $(el).closest(".tab-pane").find(".cat_id").val();
  var qty = $(el).closest(".tab-pane").find(".quantity").val();
  console.log("ID = " + catId + " Q = " + qty)
  //your ajax call..
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header p-2">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#A" data-toggle="tab">A</a></li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#B" data-toggle="tab">B</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane" id="A">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-6">
            <div class="flip-card">
              <div class="flip-card-inner">
                <div class="flip-card-front">
                  <img src="<?= base_url() ?>assets/itemdb/<?= $ditems['image']; ?>" alt="Image" style="width:200px;height:160px;">
                  <h3>
                    Oil
                  </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="flip-card-back">
                  <p><b>Price : $134</b></p>
                  <p>
                    <p>Quantity : x 77
                    </p>
                    Soemthinhs ....
                  </p>


                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
                    <!--use class here-->
                    <input type="number" value="" class="form-control quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="Enter Quantity">
                  </div>
                  <!--use class here-->
                  <input type="number" value="1" class="form-control cat_id" name="cat_id" placeholder="1" hidden>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <!--pass this inside fn which refer to this button-->
                    <button type="button" id="add_cart" class="btn" onClick="sendToCart(this);">Add To Cart</button>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="B">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-6">
            <div class="flip-card">
              <div class="flip-card-inner">
                <div class="flip-card-front">
                  <img src="<?= base_url() ?>assets/itemdb/<?= $ditems['image']; ?>" alt="Image" style="width:200px;height:160px;">
                  <h3>
                    Vegeatbles
                  </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="flip-card-back">
                  <p><b>Price : $14</b></p>
                  <p>
                    <p>Quantity : 7
                    </p>
                    Soemthinhs .... Soemthinhs ....
                  </p>


                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
                    <!--use class here-->
                    <input type="number" value="" class="form-control quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="Enter Quantity">
                  </div>
                  <!--use class here-->
                  <input type="number" value="2" class="form-control cat_id" name="cat_id" placeholder="2" hidden>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <!--pass this inside fn which refer to this button-->
                    <button type="button" id="add_cart" class="btn" onClick="sendToCart(this);">Add To Cart</button>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```